# How to sort a string list having both number and alphabets according to the highest number

Tags: python-3.x

I am looking to sort a string list numerically which has both string and number also as a string.

['har 1', 'zee 3']

expected output : 
zee 3
har 1

Answer (score 0):

You can use key-value (dictionary) for this. Then simply sort your list according to key/value using methods given in https://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2007/09/how-to-sort-python-dictionary-by-keys/

Answer (score 0):

You can sort your list with the sorted and the argument `key`

```
l = ['har 1', 'zee 3']
print(sorted(l, key=lambda x: (-int(x.split()[1]), x.split()[0])))
```

Output

```
['zee 3', 'har 1']
```

You can even print it as you wanted with the unpack operator

```
print(*sorted(l, key=lambda x: (-int(x.split()[1]), x.split()[0])), sep='\n')
```

Here I am creating from each value a tuple of (-int(second_element), first_element)

So it will sort decreasingly by the numbers, and in case of equality, it will sort alphabetically

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `key` parameter of the sorted function to specify a custom sorting order -

```
l = ['X 3', 'Z 1', 'A 2']
l_sorted = sorted(l, key=lambda x: x.split()[-1])
print(l_sorted)
/*Returns ['Z 1', 'A 2', 'X 3']*/
```